Quarkus doesn't print startup information correctly anymore
Quarkus suddenly can't print startup infos anymore:
Profile%s %s activated. %s

This used to look like this:
Profile dev activated.

The only thing I changed was to add a logging filter which also replaces newlines
quarkus.log.console.filter=DefaultConsoleFilter

Any ideas?
import io.quarkus.logging.LoggingFilter;

import java.util.logging.Filter;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;


@LoggingFilter(name = "DefaultConsoleFilter")
public class DefaultConsoleFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord record) {
        String message = record.getMessage();
        message = replaceNewline(message);
        record.setMessage(message);
        return true;
    }

    private static String replaceNewline(String message) {
        message = message.replace("\r\n", "\n").replace("\n", "\\n");
        return message;
    }
}


What version does the problem appear in?

@geoand It is quarkus 3.2.9-Final-redhat-00002

Problem was when using the setMessage() method without the second param the replacements weren't applied.
        ExtLogRecord.FormatStyle formatStyle = extLogRecord.getFormatStyle();
        String message = extLogRecord.getMessage();
        if (Objects.nonNull(message)) {
            message = replaceNewline(message);
            extLogRecord.setMessage(message, formatStyle);
        }


@ahuemmer how can i accept when he only commented?
